# Load Named Style within a group on QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, grouping, loading

I am trying to apply the style from .qml to a group of layers in QGIS. I have tried to incorporate LoadNamedStyle within jkall's code here:
https://github.com/jkall/qgis-processing-scripts/blob/master/set_transparency_for_group.py
I end up with this:

```
from qgis.core import *
def applystyle_group(name):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    point = root.findGroup(name) #Find Group AP
    for child in point.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            if child.layer().type()==0:
                child.loadNamedStyle('*.qml')
applystyle_group("AK")
```

It gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/applystyle_group.py", line 9, in <module>
     applystyle_group("AK")
  File "C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/applystyle_group.py", line 8, in applystyle_group
    child.loadNamedStyle('*.qml')
AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'loadNamedStyle'
```

Does QgsLayerTreeLayer have something similar to loadNamedStyle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line

```
child.loadNamedStyle('*.qml')
```

by:

```
child.layer().loadNamedStyle('/some/real/path/to/a/file.qml')
```

Your child object is of type `QgsLayerTreeLayer`, but you need to access `layer()` to get its correspondent `QgsMapLayer`, which has a `loadNamedStyle()` method.

Comment: Wonderful German,
You saved me again!

Comment: A-ha, don't tell me you are BC14W! :)

Comment: Haha! yes, I am! :)

Comment: Marked it as accepted. I don't have 15 reputations yet, so I can't up-vote yet.